# python 3 web scraping code for yahoo finance stock

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, stockquotes

Here is the code for Python 3 for web scraping Yahoo finance stock price of AAPL.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL")

htmltext = htmlfile.read()

for price in htmltext.find(attrs={'id':"yfs_184_aapl"}):
    print (price)
```

Apparently, the code works fine with little modification in Python 2.7. However, it does not work in Python 3.3.3 Shell. Here is the error it shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/python codes/webstock2.py", line 8, in <module>
    for price in htmltext.find(attrs={'id':"yfs_184_aapl"}):
TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments
```

I have learned to correct the string pattern to binary via str.encode. I'm not sure this I can work with this code.

Edit1: Final working code change after @Martijn

```
    import urllib.request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

    htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL")

    htmltext = htmlfile.read()

    soup = bs4(htmltext)

    for price in soup.find_all(id="yfs_l84_aapl"):
        print (price)
```

It prints out blank. Could you figure this out. thanks again.

Comment: Better yet, get the quote in CSV and skip screen-scraping altogether: http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=sl1 . More details: http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `str.find()`, **not** `BeautifulSoup.find()`. You forgot something:

```
soup = bs4(htmltext)

for price in soup.find(attrs={'id':"yfs_184_aapl"}):
```

But if you are going to loop, you need to call `find_all()`, really:

```
for price in soup.find_all(id="yfs_l84_aapl"):
```

You don't actually have to use the `attrs` keyword argument; specifying the attributes as keyword arguments directly works fine too.

You *do* have to use the correct `id` attribute; it is `yfs_l84_aapl` (letter `l`, followed by the digits `8` and `4`), not the digit `1`.

Comment: I have updated (check the code inserted in edit in the question). Unfortunately, it provide neither error nor any output value. Just blank.

Comment: Oops. Silly mistake. Thanks a lot for pointing it out. I have been scratching my head all over. :)